# childview in listview not getting clicked often

Tags: android

I have a listview and i have implemented onItemClicklistner for listview, plus i also have an image in listview on which i click to move to another screen, but what is actually happening on device is that its very difficult to detect that the image being is  clicked and 90% times the onitemclick listner of listview gets fired. How can i diffrentiate between two.

Listener for imageview

```
iv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View arg0) { 
                            int id = togglePublicationFlag(iv);
                            updateDatbase(id, iv.getTag().toString());                          
                    }
});
```

[image]

Comment: could you bother formatting a bit better the code?

Comment: http://samir-mangroliya.blogspot.in/p/android-customized-listview.html                         i put button in each row and you can put backbround for button.

Comment: ok, i got the imageview working { (+) image } by changing it to ImageButton, but now onItemClick of listview is not working...why ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the image height is simillar to the height of a ListView item,

And you can try and make the width wider with transparent background, so the image appears the same but has wider click area.

Comment: ok, i got the imageview working { (+) image } by changing it to ImageButton, but now onItemClick of listview is not working...why ?

Comment: does it through any errors or just dosen't respond? add the code to the question.